# Logistic Ridge Regression predict ROC/ AUC and accuracy testing

Tags: r

I am trying to fit Logistic Ridge Regression and developed the model as follows; I need help with the coding for testing it for accuracy and ROC/AUC curve with threshold value.

My coding is as follows:

Fitting the model

```
library(glmnet)
library(caret)

data1<-read.csv("D:\\Research\\Final2.csv",header=T,sep=",")
str(data1)
'data.frame':   154 obs. of  12 variables:
$ Earningspershare : num  12 2.69 8.18 -0.91 3.04 ...
 $ NetAssetsPerShare: num  167.1 17.2 41.1 14.2 33 ...
$ Dividendpershare : num  3 1.5 1.5 0 1.25 0 0 0 0 0.5 ...
 $ PE               : num  7.35 8.85 6.66 -5.27 18.49 ...
 $ PB               : num  0.53 1.38 1.33 0.34 1.7 0.23 0.5 3.1 0.5 0.3 ...
$ ROE              : num  0.08 0.16 0.27 -0.06 0.09 -0.06 -0.06 0.15 0.09 0.
 $ ROA              : num  0.02 0.09 0.14 -0.03 0.05 -0.04 -0.05 0.09 0.03 0
$ Log_MV           : num  8.65 10.38 9.81 8.3 10.36 ..
$ Return_yearly    : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ L3               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ L6               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Sector           : int  2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 4 1 ...

smp_size <- floor(0.8 * nrow(data1))
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(data1)), size = smp_size)
train <- data1[train_ind, ]
test <- data1[-train_ind, ]

train$Return_yearly <-as.factor(train$Return_yearly)
train$L3 <-as.factor(train$L3)
train$L6 <-as.factor(train$L6)
train$Sector <-as.factor(train$Sector)

train$L3 <-model.matrix( ~ L3 - 1, data=train)
train$L6 <-model.matrix( ~ L6 - 1, data=train)
train$Sector<-model.matrix( ~ Sector - 1, data=train)

x <- model.matrix(Return_yearly ~., train)
y <- train$Return_yearly

ridge.mod <- glmnet(x, y=as.factor(train$Return_yearly), family='binomial', alpha=0, nlambda=100, lambda.min.ratio=0.0001)

set.seed(1)
cv.out <- cv.glmnet(x, y=as.factor(train$Return_yearly), family='binomial', alpha=0, nfolds = 5, type.measure = "auc", nlambda=100, lambda.min.ratio=0.0001)
plot(cv.out)
best.lambda <- cv.out$lambda.min
best.lambda
[1] 5.109392
```

Testing the model

```
test$L3 <-as.factor(test$L3)
test$L6 <-as.factor(test$L6)
test$Sector <-as.factor(test$Sector)
test$Return_yearly <-as.factor(test$Return_yearly)

test$L3 <-model.matrix( ~ L3 - 1, data=test)
test$L6 <-model.matrix( ~ L6 - 1, data=test)
test$Sector<-model.matrix( ~ Sector - 1, data=test)

newx <- model.matrix(Return_yearly ~., test)
y.pred <- as.matrix(ridge.mod,newx=newx, type="class",data=test)
```

comparing for accuracy testing; error pops up, unable to continue

```
compare <- cbind (actual=test$Return_yearly, y.pred)
Warning message:
   In cbind(actual = test$Return_yearly, y.pred) :
   number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

Comment: Why are you using `as.matrix` for `y.pred` instead of `predict`?

Comment: Error popped without it, as :Error in cbind2(1, newx) %*% nbeta : 
  Cholmod error 'X and/or Y have wrong dimensions' at file ../MatrixOps/cholmod_sdmult.c, line 90

Answer (score 0):

Without a reproducible dataset here's a guess:

The train and test matrices have different columns as the result of converting L3 and L6 to factors. By default, as.factor() creates as many levels in a factor as there are unique values, so if by chance the train/test split has different unique values of L3 or L6, the number of dummy variables created by model.matrix() will be different as well.

Possible solution: do as.factor() *before* train/test split, or supply as.factor with the complete levels, like

```
train$L3 <- as.factor(train$L3, levels = unique(data1$L3))
```

Comment: I have tried both methods you mentioned. when "do as.factor() before train/test split" ,error pops up as "Error in terms.formula(object, data = data) : 
  'data' argument is of the wrong type". when supplied as.factor with the complete levels, as you showed, error popped up as "Error: unexpected ')' in "train$L3 <-as.factor(train$L3,levels = unique(data1$L3)))"

Comment: I like to share the data set, but I do not know how to share it on stackoverflow

Comment: The first error is probably you tried to pass in the variable `data` when your actual dataset is called `data1`. The 2nd error is because you have an extra `)` at the end.

Comment: Hi nobit, can you please elaborate  the first error, passing in the variable data when  actual dataset is called data1, I am not from a programming background. Thanks

Comment: I solved the issue and continued testing using method1. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to plot the accuracy and sensitivity.

```
ROC_Pre <- prediction(ROC_Pre, data$LSD)
ROC <- performance(ROC_Pre, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(ROC)
```